# declare a variable based on __uuidof

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, com

I'd like to set a webcam's property, say a "focus". Normally it'll look something like that (ignoring error handling):

```
CComPrt<IUnknown> unkn = ...; // doesn't matter how we get that
CComPtr<IAMCameraControl> cameraCtrl;
unkn->QueryInterface(IAMCameraControl, (void**)&cameraCtrl);
cameraCtrl->Set(CameraControl_Zoom, 123, 1);
```

The MS-specific operator `__uuidof` returns a "data type" and its result can be stored in a variable of type `IID`, like the following:

```
IID cameraCtrlType = __uuidof(IAMCameraControl);
```

My question: is there a way to declare a variable based on its `IID`? Something like that:

```
CComPrt<IUnknown> unkn = ...; // doesn't matter how we get that
CComQIPtr<decltype(reverse_of__uuid(cameraCtrlType))> cameraCtrl(unkn);
cameraCtrl->Set(CameraControl_Zoom, 123, 1);
```

I'm looking for a non-template solution here. But if there's a way to templetize that off of `IID` - I'd be interested in seeing how to do so.

As far as I understand this is not possible, at least not with C++11 or even C++17. But maybe someone way more knowledgeable than I am will prove me wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achive by that (possibly xy problem...)? If you get your uuid by use of `__uuidof(SomeType)`, you get something like `__type_of(__uuidof(SomeType))`, so why couldn't you use `SomeType` directly?

Comment: Both `IAMCameraControl` and `IAMVideoProcAmp` interfaces expose functions with same names and parameters. I'm writing a UI for UVC and am trying to reuse the same code for both scenarios. The only (textual(!), not code or binary) difference is really the name of the interface so I'm looking to unify the code to handle both in an `if(__uuidof(...) == ...)` statement. Everything works fine up to the point of specifying that `cameraCtrl` variable. As I said - I'm pretty confident this is impossible since C++ needs to know the types for function binding.

Comment: And you use both objects in the same way, too? This would then really yell for a template aproach...

Comment: I'm not stupid, I'm just curious :) Mostly about whether this is possible at all to declare a variable based on a reverse operation to `__uuid`. I don't see how to do it even for a case of a template: how to templatize based on `IID` and inside that template have a variable of type to which that `IID` refers to

Comment: Have not MS-compiler available currently to test; if at all, you might work with template specialisations: `template <uuid Id> classTypeOf>;` `template<>class Typeof<SomeUUID> { typedef SomeType type; }`. Usage: `CComQIPtr<Typeof<someUUID>::type>`. Not sure if MSVC accepts `uuid` as template parameter, though. And it would require the UUID being known at compile time! According to [MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6wkewa.aspx), if at all, this is only the case in release build if you want to use `__uuidof` for...

Comment: However, I think you are better of trying to abstract on some higher level via polymorphism, providing a common base class with some appropriate (possibly pure) virtual interface and a template class implementing this interface...

Comment: If both `IAMCameraControl` and `IAMVideoProcAmp` interfaces expose functions with same names and parameters then does this mean that they both derive / implement the common interface? If so then why don't you use them by this common interface? If not and they just happen to be the same right now then you should not try to merge them into one and use strictly separately, because otherwise you'll get in trouble when one of there classes changes or if you didn't notice some small difference between them.

Comment: OK, guys. So far the discussion is around "why do you do that?". Let me be clear - I do understand that this is not a portable, or even "correct" design. Yet this is besides the point. I'm asking a general question (was just trying to provide an example of how this could be used so it's easier to relate to). I'm **only** interested in whether there's a way to do it, not in whether this is a tasteful, or valid, or solid, or reliable, or <your favorite reason to "fix me"> solution.